# Python Modules, Pip, Cronjobs

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, pip, cron

I've been struggling all day to figure out how to correctly install a python module so that it can be accessed by a crontab. Below I've outlined the steps I'm currently taking and would love for someone to tell me where I'm making a mistake and how I could improve.

Everything looks good until I get to step 8

All feedback is definitely welcome

Step 1 - Check for beatbox

```
>>> import beatbox
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named beatbox
```

Step 2 - Install Beatbox

```
MacBook-Pro-10:~ $ sudo pip install beatboxxx
Downloading/unpacking beatboxxx
  Downloading beatboxxx-21.5.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/private/tmp/pip_build_root/beatboxxx/setup.py) egg_info for package beatboxxx

    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'examples'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'src/beatbox/tests/sfconfig.py'
Installing collected packages: beatboxxx
  Running setup.py install for beatboxxx

    warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'examples'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'src/beatbox/tests/sfconfig.py'
Successfully installed beatboxxx
Cleaning up...
```

Step 3 - Verify beatbox location

```
>>> import beatbox
>>> print beatbox.__file__
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beatbox/__init__.pyc
```

Step 4 - Check if directory is in sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>> for i in sys.path:
...     print i
... 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

Step 5 - Add Beatbox to sys.path

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beatbox')
>>> x = '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/beatbox'
>>> x in sys.path
True
>>>
```

Step 6 - Create python file importing beatbox
    MacBook-Pro-10:Desktop $ vim beatbox_test.py

```
import beatbox
~
~
```

Step 7 - Create crontab
    MacBook-Pro-10:Desktop $ crontab -e

```
*/1 * * * * python /Users/user123121231/Desktop/beatbox_test.py      

crontab: installing new crontab
```

Step 8 - Check mail for crontab success

```
MacBook-Pro-10:Desktop $ mail
"/var/mail/Message 1: 1 message 1 new

>N  1 MacBook-P  Sun Oct 26 11:11  22/889   "Cron <MacBook-Pro-10> python /Users/user123121231/Desktop/beatbox_test.py"


From User123142324@User123142324s-MacBook-Pro-10.local  Sun Oct 26 11:11:01 2014
X-Original-To: User123142324
Delivered-To: User123142324@User123142324s-MacBook-Pro-10.local
From: User123142324@User123142324s-MacBook-Pro-10.local (Cron Daemon)
To: User123142324@User123142324s-MacBook-Pro-10.local
Subject: Cron <User123142324@User123142324s-MacBook-Pro-10> python /Users/User123142324/Desktop/beatbox_test.py  
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=User123142324>
X-Cron-Env: <USER=User123142324>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/Users/User123142324>
Date: Sun, 26 Oct 2014 11:10:00 -0700 (PDT)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/User123142324/Desktop/beatbox_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import beatbox
ImportError: No module named beatbox":
```

**UPDATE: Still no solution but I found something out. I amended the beatbox_test.py to be the following:**

```
import sys
for i in sys.path:
    print i
import beatbox
```

Which returned the following:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python26.zip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-darwin
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-tk
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-old
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages
```

**Why is everything pointing to 2.6 instead of 2.7?**

Comment: you have put your question very nicely. i wonder how it got such low views. what have you done in `step 6` do it in your `beatbox_test.py` script. and check it again.

Comment: the only line in beatbox_test.py is `import beatbox`

Comment: Maybe cron is using a different version of Python than you installed beatbox for. I recommend to find out the path of th working python via `which python` and then setting an absolute path in crontab. E.g.: /usr/bin/python

Comment: it looks like crontab is using python 2.6...how do I change that?

Comment: You can do `ls /usr/bin/python*` to see all python versions that are available. If you have a custom python installation, there may be even more. It's always a good idea to link to a specific python binary. Especially when using virtualenv (which is recommended anyways).

Comment: you can explicitly call python 2.7 using `/usr/bin/python2.7` instead of `python`. also, you can change where `python` points

Comment: Haleemur, how do i change where python points?

Answer (score 1):

Use this line in crontab to point to a specific Python version (and all packages installed for it):

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python2.7 /Users/user123121231/Desktop/beatbox_test.py
```

Comment: Is there any way to change it permanently so I can just use `python` instead of `/usr/bin/python2.7`

Comment: Since there is also an `easy_install` for python2.6, you could install your package for that version as well: `sudo /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 beatboxxx`

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the full path to the appropriate python version in the crontab, otherwise the wrong version may run and will look for your installed modules in the wrong place. Assuming your program runs fine when you start it from the command line, you can use the which command to find the location of the python executable you are using.

```
 $ which python
/usr/bin/python2.7
```

Then use this path in your crontab entry to point to that specific Python version (and all packages installed for it):

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python2.7 /Users/user123121231/Desktop/beatbox_test.py
```